# is there a way to render only the partials?

Tags: mustache

Is there a way to render only the partials?

For example a `header` partial and a `footer` partial included by `home.mustache` would generate `home-all.mustache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep ! Just change the `prototype`

```
var Mustache = require('mustache');

Mustache.Writer.prototype.renderTokens = function (tokens, context, partials, originalTemplate) {
  var buffer = '';

  var token, symbol, value, tag;
  for (var i = 0, numTokens = tokens.length; i < numTokens; ++i) {
    value = undefined;
    token = tokens[i];
    symbol = token[0];
    tag = value = mustache.tags[0] + token[1] + mustache.tags[1];

    if (symbol === '#') value = this._renderSection(token, context, partials, originalTemplate);
    else if (symbol === '^') value = this._renderInverted(token, context, partials, originalTemplate);
    else if (symbol === '>') value = this._renderPartial(token, context, partials, originalTemplate);
    else if (symbol === '&') value = tag;
    else if (symbol === 'name') value = tag;
    else if (symbol === 'text') value = this._rawValue(token);

    if (value !== undefined)
      buffer += value;
  }

  return buffer;
};
```

Now it will output with only partials parsed into one template.